# Spring security not landing on custom login paged

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot, spring-security

I am wondering how I should be creating a custom login page do I need to explicitly create a controller for it? if so how would I do that?

here is my current security configuration file

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //requests for /stats page has ADMIN privileges only
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/stats").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
        //everything else ADMIN and USERS can see
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register").permitAll();          
    }
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
         return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and my temporary login page (just testing to see we can land there)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 5 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="login" action="login" method="POST">
            <label>
                Username:
                <input type="text" placeholder="username" required>
            </label>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the problem right now is whenever I try to access any page, I get the following error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Edit: Attempting to register the view using as per the guides in the comments yield the same error

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry r) {
        r.addViewController("/login.html").setViewName("login");
        r.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to set login page can be accessible without any authentication(with `permitAll`)? Like explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form

Comment: yes this still yields the same error

Comment: Sorry my bad, you were getting an error `404` which indicates the route mapping is wrong somehow. It can not find the login page that you created. How are you mapping `login.html` with `/login` path?

Comment: I'm not sure what yo mean by mapping `login.html`? I'm assuming yes it is with `/login` as that is what is referenced in `.loginPage("/login")`

Comment: If user is not logged in, you are redirecting to `/login` path, but what is rendered in there? That is the problem I guess. You can check this article which explains that you should also add a `login.html` page reference in the settings.   http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login (5. The Security Java Configuration)

Comment: I've added an edit of my attempt to add a reference according the the guide, however it results in the same error